# Create an array of classes and then instantiate objects from them

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an array of classes, then iterate through that array and instantiate objects from each of the classes in that array.

I tried the following:

```
Class[] classes = {Gummy.class, Chocolate.class, Lollipop.class};

for (Class candyClass : classes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r.nextInt(5); i++) {
        candyList.add(new candyClass(r.nextDouble() + 0.1 * 20));
    }
}
```

And I got this error:

```
CandyTester.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                candyList.add(new candyClass(r.nextDouble() + 0.1 * 20));
                                  ^
  symbol:   class candyClass
  location: class CandyTester
1 error
```

I don't really know where to proceed from here because I'm not too sure how java class relates to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `newInstance(args)`, which instantiates a new object of your class using a specific constructor.

```
Object candy = candyClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Double.class).newInstance(r.nextDouble() + 0.1 * 20);
candyList.add((Candy) candy);
```

Comment: I tried that and it said: `CandyTester.java:19: error: method newInstance in class Class<T> cannot be applied to given types` and the reason was `actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: Try `candyClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Double.class).newInstance(...)`. This should work.

Comment: I tried that and I got a different error this time: `CandyTester.java:19: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Candy` and it also said `Note: CandyTester.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`

Comment: All the classes must be a subclass of `Candy`, if you want to store it in a `List<Candy>`. Using Reflection will give you that kind of note, because using methods of this package is unsafe.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I casted it to `Candy` to avoid that error.

Comment: @Kluddizzz since the answer is accepted, but the solution is in comments please edit the answer conent to include the real solution.